# React Native Docs Example with ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The below code is from React Native Docs. As you can see, there are two function declerations with fat arrows. I understand the usage of normal parenthesis with the line containing `.... previousState => ({` etc. Here use of () is needed because it returns an object literal. However, I can't understand why do we use "(" with the callback function of the `setInterval`. I mean this line:   `setInterval(() => ( ...`. Why we do not write like `setInterval(() => { .....`

```js
class Blink extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    //HEART OF THE QUESTION. Why do we use "(" below, instead "{". Do we need to return for setInterval or just define a function to run ?
    setInterval(() => ( 
    
      //Here, "(" is normal because it returns object literal
      this.setState(previousState => ({
        isShowingText: !previousState.isShowingText
      }))
    ), 1000);
  }

  //....

}
```

Answer (score 1):

setInterval doesn't need a return. Both of these will work perfectly fine:

```
setInterval(() =>
    this.setState(previousState => ({
        counter: previousState.counter + 1 || 1
    })),
1000);
```

and this (which is not pretty without parenthesis, in my opinion):

```
setInterval(() => {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
        counter: previousState.counter + 1 || 1
    }));
}, 1000);
```

Usually parenthesis is needed for multiline returns, here is a good explanation:
http://jamesknelson.com/javascript-return-parenthesis/